# Staging Slots for Azure Web Apps for Containers are available Only in production Tier - very expensive

Tags: azure, slots, azure-web-app-for-containers

I have been developing a React SPA with Python Api using Docker and Azure Web Apps for Containers.

Now when I want to develop the production deployment process I find that there are no app service tiers which include slots other than very expensive production tiers.

Am I mistaken?

If not, is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

You could see **S1** or above price tier also support **Staging slots** when you expand `See additional options` tab.
[image]

Comment: The resource group in this instance is in "Australia East" - perhaps Azure is also filtering available app service tiers based on resource group location?  When I have time I will create a new app service in some alternative locations to see if this is the case.
Thanks.

Comment: I never heard that Azure filters available app service tiers based on location. I have created a web app for a container in "Australia East". It's the same result as my picture. See [App Service pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/linux/) with filtering the OS and location.

Comment: Thanks Nancy, unfortunately I've also had confirmation from Microsoft that slots isn't available in non-production tiers. I'm not sure how you are managing to find this feature.

Comment: Not sure, Maybe I am using a preview portal for validating it.